# Looking for a source to cite for the fact that conjugate gradient converges more slowly when matrix is positive semidefinite

Tags: numerical-optimization, gradient-descent, conjugate-gradient

This is surprisingly difficult for me to look up for some reason. I assume it's stated somewhere in a canonical textbook on the subject but I haven't been able to find anything. For a simple example, let's say the energy function we're trying to minimize is $(x-y)^2$. Then the matrix for this function is $A = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -1 \\
    -1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$, which is positive semi-definite (has an eigenvalue of zero corresponding to a translational symmetry). I'm just looking for a source for the fact that this system will converge more slowly than a similar system whose matrix is positive definite will, due to this translational symmetry.

Comment: May have some relevant commentary: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/35241/26983